Exception Handling Error for Strings and Doubles in C++
I'm trying to write a program about tater tots, but my exception handling isn't working correctly. Instead, I get the following output showing the if (DaysNumber < 7) output instead of the error message:

I have the following code (this is my main file; I have a link to my GitHub repository for the other files at the bottom of this question if you'd like to see those files as well):
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "tatertot.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int DaysNumber;
   
    // Asks the user how long it’s been since they ate tater tots
    cout << "How long has it been since you had some yummy tots?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of days: " << endl;
    cin >> DaysNumber;

    // Handles invalid inputs
   try {
       // If it’s been a week (or more) since the user ate tater tots…
        if (DaysNumber >= 7) {
            cout << "Yay! I bet those tots were delicious. Here's a recipe to try next time you want to eat tater tots: " << endl;
            cout << "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/236749/tater-tots-nachos/";
            abort();
        }

        // If the user ate tater tots recently…
        else {
            cout << "It. Is. TATER TOT TIME!" << endl;
            cout << "Go enjoy some yummy tots!" << endl;
            cout << "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/236749/tater-tots-nachos/";
            abort();
        }

    }
    catch (string e) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "I'm sorry, but your input is invalid. Could you please try again?" << endl;
        cin >> DaysNumber;
    }

    catch (double e) {
        cin.clear();
        cout << "I'm sorry, but your input is invalid. Could you please try again?" << endl;
        cin >> DaysNumber;
    }
    return 0;
};

I've tried using other methods of exception handling, and defining DaysNumber in my class file and accessor-mutator file, but to no avail. Maybe there's something I'm missing here?
Here's the link to my GitHub repository: https://github.com/NEE64/potate-repository

I don't see you throwing an exception, so how did you expect the catch blocks to be invoked?

Thank you to everyone who offered help and advice! I will be sure to remember these tips when I go back to my college classes in a couple days (and whenever I feel like writing a program again).

Your invalid input just leads to 0 being read into the variable. Nothing throws the exceptions you are trying to catch.
Like, check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt :

If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set.

Also, in general, the C++ standard library does not throw string or double exceptions, ever. I'm kind of thinking you are expecting these to be thrown when the user enters a string or a double instead of an int? C++ doesn't do magic like that.

You can ask operator>> to throw an exception on bad input. See the  cin.exceptions() method. But it will throw a std::ios_base::failure exception.

@RemyLebeau yes, you can. But, I just double-checked, he's not doing it -- and he was talking about dropping into the "<7" case, not about getting an uncaught exception. In a way, my debugging strategy tends to generally focus on what was done, not what could have been done -- I look at symptoms, I look at the code, and try to see if I can explain the symptoms with the code.

The structure of your program only makes sense to humans. Computers are too dumb to know to start over unless you are explicit.
⟶ For each of the following snippets I will list all the required includes. Generally you need only list each include once, all together at the top of the source file.
User Input
Textual input should generally be obtained as a full line of text, then attempt to convert it to what you asked for.
This is because the user will always press Enter after every requested input!
User Input • Convert String to Value
I have a little utility function that I use to try to convert user input into the desired data type. It returns either the successfully-converted value or an invalid state.
#include <ciso646>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto string_to( const std::string & s )
{
    T value;
    std::istringstream ss( s );
    return ((ss >> value) and (ss >> std::ws).eof())
        ? value
        : std::optional <T> { };
}

We can use it like this:
// EXAMPLE
std::cout << "Gimme a Double on the double: ";
std::string s;
getline( std::cin, s );
auto value = string_to <double> ( s );
if (value)
    std::cout << "Yay! " << *value << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "Booo!\n";

User Input • Prompt and Obtain Value
That prompt, get string, attempt conversion, and test is a common thing we do over and over. Let’s write yet another helper function to do all that for us:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto ask( const std::string & prompt )
{
    std::cout << prompt;
    std::string s;
    getline( std::cin, s );
    return string_to <T> ( s );
}

This makes life easier for us:
// EXAMPLE
auto value = ask <int> ( "How many days? " );
if (value)
    std::cout << "Good job! You entered " << *value << " days!\n";
else
    std::cout << "That was not an INTEGER value.\n";

User Input • Prompt and Validate
We can further improve our lives by writing yet another little utility to do all the validation for us, and return the data type we want without the obnoxious std::optional wrapping it:
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename Verify>
T ask( const std::string & prompt, Verify verify, const std::string & error_message )
{
    auto value = ask <int> ( prompt );
    if (!value or !verify( *value ))
        throw std::runtime_error( error_message );
    return *value;
}

This version of ask<>() throws a runtime exception for us if the verification function fails. We’ll see how to use it in just a second.
The Main Program
Now we are ready to use our handy helper functions to make main() easy-peasy.
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main()
try
{
    // Ask the user for an integer value
    int daysNumber = ask <int> (
        "How many days has it been since you have had some yummy tots? ",

        // Here is our validation function AND the message
        // to complain with should validation fail.
        []( int value ) { return value >= 0; },
        "Number of days must be an integer value ≥ 0." );

    // At this point we KNOW we have an integer number of days ≥ 0
    if (daysNumber > 7)
    {
        std::cout
            << "Yay! I bet those tots were delicious.\n"
            << "Here's a recipe to try next time you want to eat tater tots:\n"
            << "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/236749/tater-tots-nachos/\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout
            << "It. Is. TATER TOT TIME!\n"
            << "Go enjoy some yummy tots!\n"
            << "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/236749/tater-tots-nachos/\n";
    }

    // return 0;  // This can be omitted in C++
}

// Here we catch all errors derived from the standard exception
// class. We print the error message and terminate nicely, complete
// with an error code.
catch (const std::exception & e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
}

At this point we have a complete program! Just stick all the stuff above (except for the EXAMPLEs) into a .cpp file and give it a compile and go!
⟶ Here, I did it for you: https://godbolt.org/z/YszzvTdTK 
Notes
The program flow for our main program should not generally give the user too many opportunities to enter bad input.
⟶ Save that kind of stuff for interactive UI type programs, such as an editor or something that runs from a menu.
In other words, if the user enters something wrong, tell the user “tough beans!” and die (with an error message).
Also, using abort() is kind of like stabbing your program in the back when it still likes you. Prefer to end the program nicely. (You can do that with exceptions.)
C++ makes exception handling exceptionally easy (pun intended, sadly).
Lambdas
That weirdo []( int value ) { ... } thing is called a lambda. It is just a way of writing an in-line, unnamed function. We could have written a normal function:
bool validate_ge_0( int value )
{
    return value >= 0;
}

And used it as such:
    int daysNumber = ask <int> (
        "How many days has it been since you have had some yummy tots? ",
        validate_ge_0,  // (this is the name of the validation function)
        "Number of days must be an integer value ≥ 0." );

Loops!
You can still do stuff with loops. Just remember to be explicit, AND give the user a way to escape. Remember, you can write this to work any way you like!
template <typename T, typename Validate>
auto ask_n_times(
    unsigned n,
    const std::string & prompt,
    Validate validate,
    const std::string & error_message )
{
    if (n == 0) n = 1;
    while (n--)
    {
        auto value = ask <T> ( prompt );
        if (value and verify( *value ))
            return *value;
        std::cout << error_message << "\n";
        std::cout << n << " more tries to answer.\n";
    }
    throw std::runtime_error( error_message.c_str() );
}

And then:
int main()
{
    int evenNumber = ask_n_times <int> (
        3,
        "Even number? ",
        []( int value ) { return !(value & 1); },
        "That was not an even number." );
    ...

This should give you a good idea of how to organize your code. Remember, repetitive or common tasks can be wrapped by small helper functions, and anything you want to do multiple times must be in an explicit loop. Otherwise the program executes just like you read it, top to bottom, starting with the main() function.
Good luck!
